# Is it possible to write the following Java program in Delphi?

Tags: java, android, oop, delphi

Here is the program in Java:

```java
cardReader.searchCard(slotTypes, 60, new OnCardInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCardInfo(int retCode, CardInfoEntity cardInfo) {
        //Instruction
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwipeIncorrect() {
        //Instruction
    }

    @Override
    public void onMultipleCards() {
        //Instruction
    }
    });
```

I tried with the following instruction and don't know where to put the rest:

```delphi
var
cardInfo : JOnCardInfoListener;
begin
cardReader.searchCard(slotTypes,60,TJonCardInfoListener.Create???);

end;
```

Here is the class in JAVA: it's a third party library that I import on delphi.

```java
package com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.device.reader;

public interface OnCardInfoListener {
  void onCardInfo(int paramInt, CardInfoEntity paramCardInfoEntity);
  
  void onSwipeIncorrect();
  
  void onMultipleCards();
}
```

In the bridge file generated with java2op from the .jar file I have the following statement:

```delphi
JOnCardInfoListener = interface;//com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.device.reader.OnCardInfoListener

JOnCardInfoListenerClass = interface(IJavaClass)
['{283DE9B4-B2F7-4BED-B90E-A2C39DAB2687}']
end;

[JavaSignature('com/nexgo/oaf/apiv3/device/reader/OnCardInfoListener')]
JOnCardInfoListener = interface(IJavaInstance)
['{E65167F4-7C28-46EA-A29F-2993A714CC93}']
procedure onCardInfo(i: Integer; cardInfoEntity: JCardInfoEntity); cdecl;
procedure onMultipleCards; cdecl;
procedure onSwipeIncorrect; cdecl;
end;
TJOnCardInfoListener = class(TJavaGenericImport<JOnCardInfoListenerClass, JOnCardInfoListener>) end;
```

Can I declare another class from TJonCrardInfoListener to be able to override the onCardInfo method?

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Andreas Rejbrand : Please can you give me example?

Comment: It would depend on whether `OnCardInfoListener` is a class or an interface. If it's a class, then no, it cannot be written in Delphi

Comment: Yes it is class: so I have to find another way. Thanks for all!

Comment: Going by the Java code you just supplied, it is not a class, it's an interface. Someone needs to "unclose" the question so that it can be answered

Comment: Meanwhile, you may want to look at some of the links returned by this query: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TJavaLocal

Answer (score 1):

**Very** contrived example based on what you have supplied so far, but this should give you the idea:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  // You will need to add your import unit to the uses clause here
  Androidapi.JNI.JNIBridge;

type
  TCardInfoListener = class(TJavaLocal, JOnCardInfoListener)
  public
    { JOnCardInfoListener }
    procedure onCardInfo(i: Integer; cardInfoEntity: JCardInfoEntity); cdecl;
    procedure onMultipleCards; cdecl;
    procedure onSwipeIncorrect; cdecl;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    FListener: JOnCardInfoListener;
  public
    procedure SearchCard;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

{ TCardInfoListener }

procedure TCardInfoListener.onCardInfo(i: Integer; cardInfoEntity: JCardInfoEntity);
begin
  // Implementation of onCardInfo goes here
end;

procedure TCardInfoListener.onMultipleCards;
begin
  // Implementation of onMultipleCards goes here
end;

procedure TCardInfoListener.onSwipeIncorrect;
begin
  // Implementation of onSwipeIncorrect goes here
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.SearchCard;
begin
  if FListener = nil then
    FListener := TCardInfoListener.Create;
  cardReader.searchCard(slotTypes, 60, FListener);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. I try it!